# Php - Can I ignore/skip empty strings when using join()

Tags: php, arrays, join

I have a PHP script that shall generate a joined string based on a couple of substrings.

As an example I have provided some sample code below that takes an array of first, middle and last name and adds a linebreak between these in the join function.

The second array contains one empty string (middle name) and I want to ignore it during the join.

I would like to find a solution where I can ignore empty strings in the join() function.

Can it be done with some neat "trick", or do I have to filter the array from empty strings first?

```
// The array is designed as [firstname, middlename, lastname]
$names1 = array("John", "William", "Smith");
$names2 = array("Adam", "", "Johnson");

echo join("<br>", $names1);
echo "<br>";
echo join("<br>", $names2);

// Result:
/*
John
William
Smith

Adam
             <-- Can this empty line be ignored by some "trick"? :)
Johnson
```

**NB**. My array in the real situation contains conditions that shall be separatade by the " AND " keyword. I want to avoid results as "condition1 AND  AND condition3"

Comment: It's more idiomatic in PHP to use `implode()`, not `join()`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simply [filter out](http://php.net/array_filter) empty array items:

```
echo join('<br>', array_filter($names2, 'strlen'));
```

Comment: Note that `"0"` will also be filtered this way. Maybe `array_filter(..., 'strlen')` instead.

Comment: Haha... That was simple! Thanks! :-D

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Mike's answer and taken directly from php.net

```
// removes all NULL, FALSE and Empty Strings but leaves 0 (zero) values
$result = array_filter( $array, 'strlen' );
```

Comment: I'm not down-voting, but tempted to. Your answer is incomplete because it does not address the join part of the original question.